# how to select one letter from field[0] and the whole name from field[1]?

Tags: python

**Here is what I wish to do**

I wish to select one letter from field[0] and the whole name from field[1].

**Here is what I have achieved to do so far**

```
file = open("songs.txt","r")

#Repeat for each song in the text file
for line in file:

  #Let's split the line into an array called "fields" using the ";" as a separator:
  fields = line.split(";")

  #and let's extract the data:
  songTitle = fields[0]
  artist = fields[1]

  #Print the song
  print(songTitle + " by " + artist)

#It is good practice to close the file at the end to free up resources   
file.close()
```

**Here is a sample**

This is the songs.txt file

> Gods plan;Drake
>   Umberella;Rihanna
>   Perfect;Ed Sheeran
>   Shape of you;Ed sheeran
>   Hello; Adele
>   Thank u next; Ariana Grande
>   Love Yourself; Justin bieber
>   Confident;Demi lovato
>   Sorry not sorry;Demi Lovato
>   Back to you;Selena gomez
>   Havana; Camila cabello
>   I like it; Cardi b
>   Jumanji; B young
>   Mariah; Koomz

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question

Comment: Hello Laiba. Your question details are not enough! But I guess you are looing for is something like: 
print(fields[0][0] + fields[1] )

Comment: I want to print one letter from the first field, meaning from the songs and then the whole name of the artist from the second field. I'm not sure how to select the first letter

Comment: Try @abdullah.cu proposition. If it is not the solution, please provide the output expected from your example

Answer (score 0):

In `python`, and in most programming languages, objects that take an index can be nested.  By that, I mean that a list can contain lists which can contain lists which can contain, say, strings.  In order to access the letters in the strings, one needs to provide an index into each of the nested lists, and then into the string.  So for a list of list of list of string called `lololos`: `lololos` is a list of list of list of string; `lololos[0]` is a list of list of string; `lololos[0][0]` is a list of string; `lololos[0][0][0]` is a string; and `lololos[0][0][0][0]` is a single letter.

When you `.split` a string, you get back a list of strings.  So, `fields=line.split(";")` is actually a list containing two strings.  So, `fields[0]` is a string.  `fields[0][0]` is the first letter of the first string.

```
file = open("songs.txt","r")

#Repeat for each song in the text file
for line in file:

  #Let's split the line into an array called "fields" using the ";" as a separator:
  fields = line.split(";")

  #and let's extract the data:
  songTitle = fields[0]
  artist = fields[1]
  songTitleFirstChar = fields[0][0]

  #Print the song
  print(songTitleFirstChar + " by " + artist)

#It is good practice to close the file at the end to free up resources   
file.close()
```